# Can we Write For loop as a function?

Tags: python, for-loop

Please see some examples here

```py
I=int
R=range
listInput = lambda : [I(x) for x in input().strip(" ")]
for x in R(I(input())):
```

Since we use Int and range functions quite often and also we take inputs often so i define it like this. My question is can we write for loop in python like this.

```py
for(n) :return i for i in range(n)

for(n):
    print(for(n))
    # Or some thing else equivalent
```

For reference i can write the equivalent C/C++ code for it

```cpp
#define forn(i, n) for (int i = 0; i < int(n); i++)

scanf("%d", &n);
vector<bot> a(n);
forn(i, n) scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

Since I use for loops in Python I want to use DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) of programming, I want some equivalent function in python to get that c code done. Please
Any help is appreciate, and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "Since we use Int and range functions quite often" we do? Anyway, python doesn't have macros

Comment: `I=int,R=range`, so when ever i want to convert `str` to `int` i use `I("10")` or when i need list `list(R(10))`, its easier to write and fast since i convert `str` to `int` quite often and take lists very frequently so i convert int function to I and range function to R @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Burying universally-understood builtins behind "macros" only understandable to you seems to offer no benefit and seems like a maintenance nightmare. This is generally a poor idea in C as well, with some exceptions. It's powerful, but with great power comes great responsibility. In short, I strongly recommend against all of the practices espoused in this post most of the time. Just write regular code.

Comment: Python already lets you write much less verbose code than C, and the [Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) encourages you to be explicit and readable. Is `for i in range(n)` really too much typing compared to `forn(i, n)`? Use functions, generators and abstraction to avoid repetition.

Comment: i use for loops very much , approxmately 10times in a code , can i get something by which i ```import``` and get job done. Any ways its following DRY(Don't repeat yourself) right ? @ggorlen

Comment: DRY stands for "don't repeat yourself", not "write code nobody else will ever understand". That latter principle is called WCNEWEU, and is also a great way to get fired. Everybody knows what `int` and `range` do. Nobody knows what `I` and `R` do. Code isn't for you; it's for lots of people. Remember, you only write a line of code once, but others (and you) are going to read it several times.

Comment: @ConfusedMind that sort of thing would never pass code review where I work. `I` and `R` are your own little abbreviations, but they are much less readable and offer essentially no advantage other than writing a couple less keystrokes.

Comment: This has nothing to do with DRY, an often-misunderstood term. DRY doesn't apply to calls like `range` -- it's a builtin, call it when you need it, no further abstraction is necessary (if it was, the language would provide it). `R=range` is purely obfuscation/golfing. Also, as mentioned, `range` is generally considered unpythonic when used excessively.

Comment: It's possible to do AST-based rewriting to accomplish what you're asking for here, but it's certainly not a good idea. If you're looking for a Python-inspired language where macros are a first-class feature and not something that can be implemented only hackily, might I suggest taking a look at [Boo](https://boo-language.github.io/)? (But if you want _great_ macro support, far beyond what can be done in C, the place to start is the LISP family; see Clojure's `core.async` for an example -- Go-style CSP implemented as a library with no compiler or runtime changes required).

Comment: C++ and python samples don't work. This feels a bit like the output one might expect from a machine learning system mimicking stackoverflow questions but with real people assigned to defend its questions.

Comment: Mind, even experienced LISP folk (like experienced C developers) consider using macros a bad idea when they aren't truly necessary, and I'd argue that that applies here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, but you probably shouldn't:

```
def forn(n):
    def new_func(func):
        for i in range(n):
           func(i)
        return func
    return new_func

@forn(10)
def f(i):
    print(i)
```

or this:

```
def forn(n, func)
    return [func(i) for i in range(n)]

x = forn(10, lambda x: x**2)
```

But these are more verbose and less readable than

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

or

```
x = [i**2 for i in range(10)]
```

As others have said, you'll do best to just use the built-in tools.